# Join four tables involving LEFT JOIN without duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sqlalchemy, left-join

I want to join four tables with *null* values and without duplicates and afterwards translate it into an SQLAlchemy query.

The tables are (simplified):

```
Category(id, name)
Task(id, category.id, name)
User(id, name)
```

And an many-to-many table:

```
Solved(task.id, user.id)
```

I want to get all tasks with their category and a column with an specific user who solved the task:

```
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| category.name | task.name | user.name |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| abc           | abctask1  | <null>    |
| abc           | abctask2  | luke      |
| def           | deftask1  | <null>    |
| ghi           | ghitask1  | <null>    |
| ghi           | ghitask2  | luke      |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

At the moment I've got 3 to 4 individual SQLAlchemy-queries to perform that task. If possible, it should be merged into only one query to avoid too many reads on the database.

So far I've got:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  cat.name, t.name, u.name
FROM
  Task t
JOIN 
  Category cat ON cat.id = t.category_id
LEFT JOIN 
  Solved s ON s.task_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN 
  User u ON s.user_id = u.id AND
  u.name = 'luke'
ORDER BY
  cat.name
```

But, although `DISTINCT`, I got duplicates from all rows with the given user:

```
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| category.name | task.name | user.name |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| abc           | abctask1  | <null>    |
| abc           | abctask2  | luke      |
| abc           | abctask2  | <null>    | <-- duplicate
| def           | deftask1  | <null>    |
| ghi           | ghitask1  | <null>    |
| ghi           | ghitask2  | luke      |
| ghi           | ghitask2  | <null>    | <-- duplicate
+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Is there a possibility to get this table with one query and translate it to SQLAlchemy?

Comment: For the record: DISTINCT will only coalesce rows which are *exactly the same*.  It will not remove "almost-duplicates" like those shown in the OP.

Comment: There are no duplicates in the displayed result. Seems like you actually want distinct *tasks* in the result (exactly one row per task) - with the given user only if s(he) solved it? BTW, `User` is not a valid table name without double quotes (reserved word).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `LEFT JOINS`:

- The 1st left join can join to multiple rows from `solved`. Say, 'jane' and 'luke' solved the task.
- The 2nd left join can only join to users named 'luke' ('luke' in the join condition!).

You still get ***both*** rows, 'jane' is just not shown, the join condition filters her out, but the `LEFT JOIN` preserves the row in the result anyway and appends NULL values.

You can achieve what you are after by using **parentheses** and an `[INNER] JOIN` instead of the `LEFT JOIN` between `solved` and `users`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> Use parentheses if necessary to determine the order of nesting. In the
>   absence of parentheses, `JOIN`s nest left-to-right.

```
SELECT c.name AS cat_name, t.name AS task_name, u.name AS user_name
FROM   task t
JOIN   category c ON cat.id = t.category_id
LEFT   JOIN
      (solved s JOIN users u ON u.id = s.user_id AND u.name = 'luke') ON s.task_id = t.id
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 3;
```

- Using table name `users` instead of the reserved word <strike>`user`</strike>.
- Assuming that `users.name` is defined **unique** or you can have multiple users named 'luke'.
- If `(task.id, users.id)` in `solved` is defined `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`, you don't need `DISTINCT` at all.

The resulting query is not only correct, but also faster.

---

**SqlAlchemy version of the above query:** ([contributed by @van](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99594/van))
This assumes that `Category`, `Task` and `User` are mapped classes, while `solved` is instance of `Table` (just an association table as shown in code example [Many to Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many)):

```
user_name = 'luke'
q = (session.query(Category.name, Task.name, User.name)
     .select_from(Task)
     .join(Category)
     .outerjoin(
         join(solved, User,
              (solved.c.user_id == User.id) & (User.name == user_name),
         ))
     .order_by(Category.name, Task.name, User.name)
     )
```

Comment: Good explanation and the solution works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your data, ie you probably have 2 task called abctask2/ ghitask2. Maybe you should put a constraint on the taskname. You query works well.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4647c/4

Try to check with

```
SELECT category_id, name ,count(*) from TASK GROUP BY category_id, name HAVING COUNT(*)<>1
```

Comment: There is an explanation without duplicates in the data.