# Count columns of joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, aggregate-functions

I am writing a query to summarize the data in a Postgres database:

```
SELECT products.id, 
   products.NAME, 
   product_types.type_name AS product_type, 
   delivery_types.delivery, 
   products.required_selections, 
   Count(s.id)                AS selections_count, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN ss.status = 'WARNING' THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END)                AS warning_count 
FROM   products 
   JOIN product_types 
     ON product_types.id = products.product_type_id 
   JOIN delivery_types 
     ON delivery_types.id = products.delivery_type_id 
   LEFT JOIN selections_products sp 
          ON products.id = sp.product_id 
   LEFT JOIN selections s 
          ON s.id = sp.selection_id 
   LEFT JOIN selection_statuses ss 
          ON ss.id = s.selection_status_id 
   LEFT JOIN listings l 
          ON ( s.listing_id = l.id 
               AND l.local_date_time BETWEEN 
                   To_timestamp('2014/12/01', 'YYYY/mm/DD' 
                   ) AND 
                   To_timestamp('2014/12/30', 'YYYY/mm/DD') ) 
GROUP  BY products.id, 
      product_types.type_name, 
      delivery_types.delivery
```

Basically we have a product with selections, these selections have listings and the listings have a `local_date`. I need a list of all products and how many listings they have between the two dates. No matter what I do, I get a count of all selections (a total). I feel like I'm overlooking something. The same concept goes for `warning_count`. Also, I don't really understand why Postgres requires me to add a `group by` here.

The schema looks like this (the parts you would care about anyway):

```
products
  name:string
, product_type:fk
, required_selections:integer
, deliver_type:fk

selections_products
  product_id:fk
, selection_id:fk

selections
  selection_status_id:fk
, listing_id:fk

selection_status
  status:string

listing
 local_date:datetime
```

Comment: Your version of Postgres? Where does `f` in `count(f)` come from? When you write `how many listings`, do you want to count listings twice, if two selections of the same listing contain the same product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it you `LEFT JOIN` to all selections irregardless of `listings.local_date_time`.

There is room for interpretation, we would need to see actual table definitions with all **constraints** and data types to be sure. Going out on a limb, my educated guess is you can fix your query with the use of parentheses in the `FROM` clause to prioritize joins:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.name
     , pt.type_name AS product_type
     , dt.delivery
     , p.required_selections
     , count(s.id) AS selections_count
     , sum(CASE WHEN ss.status = 'WARNING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS warning_count
FROM   products       p
JOIN   product_types  pt ON pt.id = p.product_type_id
JOIN   delivery_types dt ON dt.id = p.delivery_type_id
LEFT   JOIN (  -- LEFT JOIN!
          selections_products sp
   JOIN   selections s  ON s.id  = sp.selection_id  -- INNER JOIN!
   JOIN   listings   l  ON l.id  = s.listing_id     -- INNER JOIN!
                       AND l.local_date_time >= '2014-12-01'
                       AND l.local_date_time <  '2014-12-31'
   LEFT   JOIN selection_statuses ss ON ss.id = s.selection_status_id
   ) ON sp.product_id = p.id
GROUP  BY p.id, pt.type_name, dt.delivery;
```

This way, you first eliminate all selections outside the given time frame with `[INNER] JOIN` *before* you `LEFT JOIN` to products, thus keeping *all* products in the result, including those that aren't in any applicable selection.

Related:

- [Join four tables involving LEFT JOIN without duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482525/join-four-tables-involving-left-join-without-duplicates/31486181#31486181)

While selecting *all or most products*, this can be rewritten to be ***faster***:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.name
     , pt.type_name AS product_type
     , dt.delivery
     , p.required_selections
     , COALESCE(s.selections_count, 0) AS selections_count
     , COALESCE(s.warning_count, 0)    AS warning_count
FROM   products       p
JOIN   product_types  pt ON pt.id = p.product_type_id
JOIN   delivery_types dt ON dt.id = p.delivery_type_id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT sp.product_id
        , count(*) AS selections_count
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE ss.status = 'WARNING') AS warning_count
   FROM   selections_products sp
   JOIN   selections          s  ON s.id  = sp.selection_id
   JOIN   listings            l  ON l.id  = s.listing_id
   LEFT   JOIN selection_statuses ss ON ss.id = s.selection_status_id
   WHERE  l.local_date_time >= '2014-12-01'
   AND    l.local_date_time <  '2014-12-31'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) s ON s.product_id = p.id;
```

It's cheaper to aggregate and count selections and warnings per `product_id` first, and *then* join to products. (Unless you only retrieve a small selection of products, then it's cheaper to reduce related rows first.)

Related:

- [Why does the following join increase the query time significantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970357/why-does-the-following-join-increase-the-query-time-significantly/18971600#18971600)

---

> Also, I don't really understand why Postgres requires me to add a group by here.

Since Postgres 9.1, the PK column in `GROUP BY` covers all columns of the *same* table. That does *not* cover columns of *other* tables, even if they are functionally dependent. You need to list those explicitly in `GROUP BY` if you don't want to aggregate them.

My second query avoids this problem on the outset by aggregating *before* the join.

---

Aside: chances are, this doesn't do what you want:

```
l.local_date_time BETWEEN To_timestamp('2014/12/01', 'YYYY/mm/DD')
                      AND To_timestamp('2014/12/30', 'YYYY/mm/DD')
```

Since `date_time` seems to be of type `timestamp` (not `timestamptz`!), you would *include* '2014-12-30 00:00', but *exclude* the rest of the day '2014-12-30'. And it's always better to use ISO 8601 format for dates and timestamps, which is means the same with *every* locale and `datestyle` setting. Hence:

```
WHERE  l.local_date_time >= '2014-12-01'
AND    l.local_date_time <  '2014-12-31'
```

This includes *all* of '2014-12-30', and nothing else. No idea why you chose to exclude '2014-12-31'. Maybe you really want to include all of Dec. 2014?

```
WHERE  l.local_date_time >= '2014-12-01'
AND    l.local_date_time <  '2015-01-01'
```

Comment: excellent answer -- really appreciate you taking the time to explain it so well. accepted.