# LEFT JOIN using a link table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

There are tables `people`, `people_has_book` and `books`. I want all people in my list but not everybody has a book, so I use a `LEFT JOIN` to link `people` to `people_has_book`, but linking `people_has_book` to books should not be a `LEFT JOIN`.

How would I do this?

Comment: Well, if you have to make the join between `people_has_book` and `books` an outer join otherwise the hole "join chain" behaves like an inner join. Why do you think you shouldn't do that?

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would do this?

Comment: `... from people p left join people_has_book phb on phb.people_id = p.id left join books b on phb.book_id = b.id`

Comment: I tested a simple case and indeed it worked, but I noticed somehow in more extensive cases I got some strange results, but I'm not sure which cases that would be... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **parentheses** to prioritize joins. Like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   people p
LEFT   JOIN ( people_has_book pb JOIN books b USING (book_id) ) USING (people_id);
```

This is subtly **different** from two `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM   people p
LEFT   JOIN people_has_book pb USING (people_id)
LEFT   JOIN books b USING (book_id);
```

The latter would show rows from `people_has_book` even if there is no related entry in `books`. **However**, in a classic many-to-many implementation with FK constraints enforcing referential integrity, there is typically no effective difference for your particular query, since all `people_has_book.book_id` must reference an existing row in `books` anyway - with the exotic exception of NULL values. (If `(people_id, book_id)` is the PK of `people_has_book`, both columns are `NOT NULL` automatically.)

Related:

- [Join four tables involving LEFT JOIN without duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482525/join-four-tables-involving-left-join-without-duplicates/31486181#31486181)
- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: This is it! Thank you!